# Use directcast to call a list

Tags: vb.net, list, directcast

I'm looking for a way to avoid using select case to access a specific list; I'll have about 90 lists on a module, and depending on a record selected on a listbox (manually populated with the name of most of the tables of my database, but not all of them) I need to read the items of the list. So I have something like this:

```vb
Public RelevantTables_Table001 As List(Of Table001) = New List(Of Table001)
Public RelevantTables_Table002 As List(Of Table002) = New List(Of Table002)
'...
Public RelevantTables_Table999 As List(Of Table999) = New List(Of Table999)

Class Table001
'code for populating RelevantTables_Table001
End Class

Class Table002
'code for populating RelevantTables_Table002
End Class

Class Table999
'code for populating RelevantTables_Table999
End Class
```

And now I need to read the relevant list, depending on an item picked on a listbox. For example if someone picks `Table042` I need to read the items of the list `RelevantTables_Table042`.

I'm trying to use DirectCast for this, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: How are you filling the listbox? Update your post with that.

Comment: right now, manually; the listbox lists most of the tables of my database.

Comment: `Reflection` is a possibility since you could create a string of the `"RelevantTables_" & lsb.Text` = RelevantTables_Table001 and that would be the name of the field.

Comment: it would help to know a little about what these things are.  is `List(Of Table002)` literally a list of Table002 objects or a list of Things *for* a new Table2 object?  Do the tables classes use inheritance?

Comment: I'm reading about how to use reflection for this, i've only used it to access some dll's i've created before. List(Of Table002) is literally a list of Table002 objects; on load, i run something like RelevantTables_Table002.Add(New Table002("NameOfTable", "IDfield", "Table Name Alias")) to fill all the list objects with the strings i want. I'm just tring to find a way to call a list not by his name, but by using a variable: read list "RelevantTables_" & lsb.Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class:

```
Public Class Table
  Public Tablename As String
  Public Collection As New List(Of String)
  Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return Me.TableName
  End Function
End Class
```

Create new List:

```
Private RelevantTable_Table001 As New Table
RelevantTable_Table001.Tablename = "Table001"
RelevantTable_Table001.Collection.Add("stuff")
...
'add the class and it will display the TableName since we 
'overrided the ToString function 
lsb.Items.Add(RelevantTable_Table001)
'class objects can be stored in the listbox as an object
```

Get the List object from the `SelectedItem` property.

```
Private Sub lsb_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Dim tableList = TryCast(DirectCast(sender, ListBox).SelectedItem, Table)
  If tableList IsNot Nothing Then
    'tableList is the reference to the table object you seek.
  End If
End Sub
```

To make a list of several objects(columns in a DGV) use a custom class:

```
Public Class MyCustomClass
  Public Property Prop1 As String
  Public Property Prop2 As String
  Public Property Prop3 As String
End Class
```

Then your `Table.Collection` would be a `List(Of MyCustomClass)` instead of a string, this will give you 3 items per collection items - which is a table. Does that fit your needs?

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for :) Can i trouble you with just a last question? it would help me a lot if I could create lists with multiple columns (i need 3). i have code to do it, and i'm trying to apply it over the code you provide. Apart from that, thank you guys one more time for your kind help

Comment: @user3050422, will this do?

Comment: Totally OneFineDay, i have this issue solved. Thank you so much mate, you really helped me here :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of lists, then use the subscript to access the correct list, such as

```
Public RelevantTables As List(Of List(Of table)) 

For Each item in RelevantTables(42)
```